# Decompressing multiple files using LZ4

Tags: unix, lz4

I have a set of compressed lz4 files(40), which is around 50GB. Need to de-compress that. Using following code to decompress.

```
lz4 -d -m fileA fileB fileC fileD....
```

It's taking hours to decompress in 2 sockets machine with 32 cores and 256gb RAM. But it's using only single core. As per documentation, lz4 is multithreaded.

So i divided the task as 4 different tasks

```
nohup lz4 -d fileA fileB &
nohup lz4 -d fileC fileD &
nohup lz4 -d fileE fileF &
nohup lz4 -d fileG fileH &
```

But still, it's taking 1.5 hrs to complete. Total decompressed data is around 1.1TB.

What would be the best approach to attain maximum performance?

Comment: Isn't it the disk write speed that holds all this up? I think I had a benchmark 8 yrs ago that Enterprise grade HD wrote at 1GB per minute (approx) (or was it 1GB per sec, don't think so). And when you're writing multiple files at the same time, if it's going to the same disk/platter, that will slow things up too. Good luck.

Comment: I anticipate the same.Thanks